# Error: Plugin with id 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0' not found

Tags: android, firebase

I have integrated firebase with my help and I'm having this initial error while syncing the app. What can be the possible issue, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: do you add this: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at **bottom** of gradle.build ?

Comment: yes I have added this.!

Comment: Also note that if you want to use version of 9.2.0 your PlayServices in SDK manager should be updated. check with lower version of PlayServices ( eg. 9.0.0) if this issue is gone then it's related to your PlayServices.

Comment: post your application and project level `build.gradle` files

Answer (score 4):

I needed to add `classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.2.0'`, worked for me after that.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add the dependencies for the Firebase SDKs you wish to use -  see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have Google Play Service version 31 installed in the Android SDK Manager.

[image: Android SDK Manager with Google Play Service version 31 installed]